# Función para traer datos de usuario de json

Tags: php, json

Estoy intentando listar determinados datos de mi archivo ***usuario.json***,
tengo este código que lo vi en una plataforma de estudio, en la plataforma toma esta respuesta como valida, pero al querer usarlo en mi proyecto algo falla.

En principio me dice que **'$arrayUsuario' no es un array**.

> Warning: array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array,
>
> Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array

```
function buscarPorEmail($email) {
    $usuarios= file_get_contents("usuario.json");
      $arrayUsuarios = json_decode($usuarios, true);
      $busqueda= array_column($arrayUsuarios, "email");
      $index= array_search($email, $busqueda);
      if ($index !==  false) {
        $user=$arrayUsuarios[$index];
        return $user;
      }
      
    }
```

Comment: Sería de mucha ayuda que pudieras publicar el formato del json el cual quieres recorrer.

Comment: Si puedes facilitar el contenido del archivo usuario.json podremos ayudarte mejor, sin él, no podemos decirte si realmente es un array o no... Haz un "echo $arrayUsuarios" para conocer lo que te está leyendo. 

Para que tu archivo sea un array, debe tener algo parecido a esto:
    {
      [
        {Datos de usuario}
      ]
    }

Saludos!

Comment: con json_decode no estoy transformando el string de json en un array?
el archivo json esta escrito asi
{"nombre":"asd","apellido":"asd","email":"asd@asd.com","password":"$2y$10$CqPCtNhIXSQxfCWv69h3j.N9EdttNYC4xv5P9be2Rv.dqyc5KVx.i","ciudad":"asd","barrio":"asd","postal":"1414","nacimiento":"1990"}

Comment: si quitas el email, seguramente sí te funcione.... No sé porqué, ahora voy a comer, luego le echo un vistazo.

Comment: Revisa por favor el formato de tu archivo json, fijate que si le pones $usuarios= file_get_contents("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"); carga el json que puedes ver aquí: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users que tiene un formato que sí funciona con tu script. Seguramente allí está tu inconveniente. Si no te llegás a dar cuenta porqué por favor copia el Json COMPLETO así podemos verlo.

Comment: Pedro, con ese formato si me funciona. Será que no estoy transformando el string en un array?

Comment: @FernandoSardone Json es por definición un string (con cierto formato específico, pero un string al fin), por lo que no debes hacer ningún proceso de transformación, más bien yo validaría el json (lo puedes validar aquí: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) para descartar cualquier error, y paso siguiente compararía su estructura con el provisto que si funciona, allí tiene que estar el error. Si puedes envía el json completo que estás intentando procesar, asi es mas fácil debuggear.

Comment: $jusuario = json_encode($usuariofinal);
    file_put_contents("usuario.json", $jusuario . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);

 con este script estoy guardando el usuario, creo que acá esta el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Hola el arrayUsuarios para que funcione, debe estar representado de esta forma.

```
$arrayUsuarios = array($arrayUsuarios);
```

Quedando finalmente asi.

```
function buscarPorEmail($email) {
    $usuarios= file_get_contents("usuario.json");
    //$usuarios= file_get_contents("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1");
    $arrayUsuarios = json_decode($usuarios, true);

    $arrayUsuarios = array($arrayUsuarios);

    $busqueda= array_column($arrayUsuarios, "email");
    $index= array_search($email, $busqueda);
    if ($index !==  false) {
        $user=$arrayUsuarios[$index];
        return $user;
    }else{
        return "No se encontro nada";
    }

}

echo var_dump(buscarPorEmail("Sincere@april.biz"));
```

Pero esto solo funciona si tu json, esta en este formato que comentaste.

```
{"nombre":"asd","apellido":"asd","email":"asd@asd.com","password":"$2y$10$CqPCtNhIXSQxfCWv69h3j.N9EdttNYC4xv5P9be2Rv.dqyc5KVx.i","ciudad":"asd","barrio":"asd","postal":"1414","nacimiento":"1990"}
```